# Proper way to use try and except with multiple with opens

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a log.csv and db.csv file.  If they both contain the same number, nothing happens.  If db.csv has a larger number, log.csv will be updated with the same number as db.csv

My current code notifies which file is missing if it does not exist.  Is this the proper way to use try and except?  Or should I be using a try and except for every single 'with open' statement?

```
import time
import os

def locate():

    while True:

        time.sleep(8)
        try:
            with open("log.csv", "rb") as f:  # Open local log for read
                for number in f:
                    log_number = number
                    with open("db.csv", "rb") as f2:  # Open db for write

                        # Will read database here
                        for first_line in f2:
                            db_number = first_line

                            if db_number > log_number:
                                print ("We have a new winner!")
                                with open("log.csv", "wb") as f:
                                    f.write(db_number)
                                    break
                            else:
                                print ("Number is the same.")
                                break
        except OSError as e:
            print (e)
            break

locate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not open multiple on a single line? Opening any file repeatedly in a loop without it actually depending on the loop variable is terribly inefficient

```
with open("log.csv", "rb+") as log, open("db.csv", "rb") as db:
    for log_number in log:
```

However, if you actually wanted a proper database use the `sqlite3` module and create SQL tables in a single database file, not maintain separate files. Also a selection where a user already exists, or finding a max are straightforward operations then

Comment: Thank you.  Yeah I'm actually using SQL Server.  I will be using pypyodbc instead of the db.csv.